system kernel tracing folder missed in ubuntu 22
/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/ or /sys/kernel/tracing/ is missing from UBUNTU 22 AWS instance.
We have rebooted to a different kernel and the tracing folder is missing suddenly due to some human error. Could you please suggest how to get this folder, or even how to rebuild this folder?
Thanks.

There are no details in this question that can be used to help you. Starting with the version are you running Ubuntu Core 22 as that is the only version that uses just the one number. If you are not using Ubuntu Core please edit and give the correct version info. What kernel did you start with? What kernel are you trying to use? Please edit the question give the 2 bits of info asked as well as a more complete description of your physical setup.

Perhaps someone stopped the mount unit(s)? check with systemctl status sys-kernel-{tracing,debug}.mount for example

@DavidDE, Kernel and os versions are as follows. Kernel :6.5.0-1023-aws,  OS details:at /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy

@steeldriver, mountunits services is running fine.
